# How to get the user information using the user lookup ID from fields property when accessing items from a share-point list using Ms Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am accessing a Share-point list using the MS graph API endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields
```

I am getting the list items just fine, but I also want to get the user information attached in each field. The data item returned looks like this:

```
      {
            ...other properties,
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"eTag,1\"",
                "id": "1",
                "ContentType": "Item",
                "Title": "<Some Title>",
                "Modified": "<modified dateTime>",
                "Created": "<created dateTime>",
                "AuthorLookupId": "12",
                "EditorLookupId": "12",
                "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "Edit": "",
                "LinkTitleNoMenu": "<num>",
                "LinkTitle": "<num>",
                "ItemChildCount": "0",
                "FolderChildCount": "0",
                "_ComplianceFlags": "",
                "_ComplianceTag": "",
                "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
                "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
                "Status_Name": "<status_name>",
                "Title0": "<some_title>",
                "Dept": "Dept A",
                "Emp_LeadLookupId": "200", //This is the user whose details I need(email-id)
                "Quality_Approver": "<some_user>"
            }
        }
```

How do I get the user's details as well and not just a LookupId, OR how can I use the look up ID to get the said user's information?
I searched above and beyond but didn't find anything relevant. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently Microsoft Graph is not support the function of finding users through the lookup column.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my site:

```
https://{site}.sharepoint.com.mcas.ms/sites/{sharepoint site}/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx
```

shows out the hidden list that SharePoint uses internally for looking up a user or group, I got the hidden user list on the URL Chrome toolbar.

Later:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{your id site}/lists/{yourhiddenuserlist}//items/{lookupUserId}?$expand=Fields($select=title,name,email,id)
```

…and it will show you the info.